How to plot a scatter-chart in excel with text on the x-axis?
I would like some help with creating a graph in Excel. My goal is to plot a graph where the X-axis represents the names of the samples, and the Y-axis shows the corresponding values. Additionally, there may be multiple values for each sample.
Here’s a rough representation of what I’m aiming for:
4|       .  .
3|       . 
2|  .  .
1|  .
 |__ __ __ __
0   A  B  C  D

Is it possible to create such a graph in Excel?
Thank you in advance!
Best regards,
Y
I could not have text on the x-axis, it only showed numbers.

based on this site use a line chart is satisfactory?

@Blackcat Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need!
